# Hyperlink to a random page

Tags: hyperlink

Is there a way to include a hyperlink on a page that sends you to a random page in your pdf (which is different each time)?

If I try to use pgf, I can output a random number within a certain range, but I don't know how to make part of a command instead of something that latex will print.

```
\usepackage{pgf} 

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} % to ensure that it is randomized
\newcommand{\thecmd}[1]{% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{int(#1-#1/4)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{int(#1+#1/4)}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thenum}{int(random(\a,\b))}%
\thenum%
}%

\newcommand{\random}{\thecmd{4}}

\begin{document}
\hyperlink{page.\random}{ 1}

\newpage
\newpage
\newpage
\newpage
\newpage
```

Comment: different time each time you make the pdf document ( a tex question, answer yes) or each time you click on it (a pdf and/or http server question)

Comment: Each time you click on it.

Comment: give a fixed url to your web server then configure your webserver to redirect to yourpdf.pdf#randompage so it's not really a tex question

Comment: I want to use this on the remarkable 2, so this probably won't work.

Comment: well pdf on its own cant do it, some pdf reader may allow nough javascript but I doubt it. The whole point of pdf compared to postscript is that it has no computational functionality.

Comment: Could you do it if it's random every time you make the pdf document?

Comment: yes expl3 or pgf have random number generators for example so you just use the random number to generate your page links